# What are the best practices to use arrays as function arguments?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm an intermediate programmer who works with PHP mostly. Recently, I noticed that many PHP developers use arrays as function arguments in their code. I'm little sceptic of using arrays like that, as some of the people in my workplace said that it's not the best practice.

For example, I have this piece of code in one of my WordPress projects right now, it might not make sense to you completely, but it's relevant:

```
<?php
/**
 * Print a list of featured posts.
 *
 * @param  $args Array  Function Arguments
 * @return $html String The final markup
 */
if( function_exists( 'abc_featured_posts_list' ) ) :
  function abc_featured_posts_list( $args = array(
    'number'  => 8,
    'image'   => 'path/to/default.image',
    'wrapper' => false,
    'style'   => 'minimal'
  ) ) {
    // Storage for the list markup
    $html = null;

    ...
    ...

    return html;
  }
endif;  
?>
```

It's the first time I'm passing arguments like this in a PHP function. Is it the right way to do that? What is the advantage of using an array over a bunch of variables in such a case?

Comment: *It depends, as always.* The big drawback is that it's basically untyped and hard to predict, inspect or refactor. But it's pretty simple. Arguably a function shouldn't accept *that many arguments* to begin with. If it needs to, a config object or other OOP approach would probably help.

Comment: You're asking questions in order to satisfy imaginary programming criticist, but you never ask what the gain is. You need to gain something when you apply a technique, approach etc. Also, wordpress and best practices.. sounds like an excellent intro to a joke.

Comment: @deceze That sounds good to me. I'll try to go the OOP way to find out more. Thanks for your response :)

Comment: @N.B. I believe there can be best practices everywhere there exists a community. I asked if it's the right way to do such kind of programming tasks, which I think covers asking about the goods and the bads both. Chill.

Comment: My two cents (this is just my opinion), is that using an array as argument is OK if it is something like filtering some results (like a bunch of search criteria etc like WP's [get_posts()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts)), where none of the parameters are required and where any combination is valid. If you have arguments that are required or critical, then they should be their own arguments. It's important that you document all possible parameters though.

Comment: For every argument that supports your decision, I can find the other that counters it and vice-versa. Your question is general, but then you gave it context (wordpress). However, the *only* way to determine if it's ok or not for the context (wordpress and working with your co-workers) is to ask - what's the *gain*? So, what's the gain?